# Generate Report(.docx) from Excel Web Part

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

Basically I am generating report .docx and .pdf format from the Excel file. The excel file is displayed as Excel Webpart and allowing the user to edit the excel file.

To Save the excel file:

I am following this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office2010developertrainingcourse_solutiondevelopmentexcelserviceslab_topic4#_Toc289085983) to save the user changes to excel file. A link button with JavaScript code which calls Excel Webservice to save the Workbook to the document library.

To Generate reports:

I am using Open Xml sdk to retrieve values from the Excel in to the Word document. This is a webpart with a button.

I am planning to do both the activities in a single button click. So,

1. Is there any way to save the user changes in the Excel web parts using C# instead of Javascript?
2. Or how do I call Javascript first from my Webpart C# code?

I would really appreciate if you could help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any detail about the first approach, but you can register a client event using RegisterStartupScript function like shown in [here](http://blog.helloitsliam.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=37) in codebehind.

Comment: Thanks for that.. But I am looking for the approach to use C# to save the changes in Excel Webparts.